Resturn results items by sorting by nearest location
I got managed properties crawled (in sp2016) of the Lat and Long coordinates of our offices location.
I trying to het the nearest location to given coordinates by using rest api query.
I using following formula with the query but its not accurate :
query:
ContentSource:contentsourceName (mplatCoord>29.353182511178655 AND mplatCoord<34.779412908921344 AND mplongCoord>32.0841928180263 AND mplongCoord<37.473808618026304)
sorting:
[
{
"Property": "[formula:abs(32.06629771005-MpLatCoord)+abs(34.7790007180263-MplongCoord)]",
"Direction": "0"
}
]
what am i doing wrong
